Could not install my un-published Google Workspace add-on
I developed a Google Workspace add-on in Google App Script. I tried to test the add-on by follow this guide: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons, which says that:

Follow these steps to install an unpublished Google Workspace Add-on for testing:
Open the script project in the Apps Script editor.
Click Deploy > Test deployments.
Click Install.
At the bottom, click Done.

However, I do not see my extension in the "Managed add-ons". Here is my manifest file: https://pastebin.pl/view/26f606c9
I expected to see my add-on in the Managed add-on list on Google Spreadsheet. I made sure the open the spreadsheet in my Google account and have tried to reset my browser cache + uninstall/install the add-on several times.

Creating a test deployment doesn't make an add-on appear on the Extensions > Add-ons > Manage Add-ons dialog.
From Create and manage deployments > Archive a versioned deployment

Archive a versioned deployment
You can't delete versioned deployments. Instead, you can archive them.
To archive a versioned deployment:

Open the Apps Script project.
Click Deploy > Manage deployments.
Select the deployment you want to archive and click Archive deployment archive.


